# Rebuild .vbox with snapshots?

Tags: virtualbox

Virtualbox has recently damaged a .vbox and .vbox-prev file on a guest virtual machine that has several snapshots, leaving a 3 kb .vbox file with just the machine uuid and default settings.

All .VDI files are still intact, including the snapshots in the \Snapshots directory.

I can rebuild the virtual machine, but how can I re-attach the Snapshots to the virtual machine? (Is it possible?)

Comment: Thanks - the .vbox-prev file was also smashed I'm afraid - probably by a close then re-open of VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I restored my snapshots with a dodgy workaround:

Take a snapshot of the newly recreated Virtualbox machine before doing anything else - so we don't modify the base .vdi file.

Launch the VM then shut it down - take a snapshot - name the snapshot something you can search for later, e.g. "temp snapshot".

Close Virtualbox.

Edit the .vbox file in a text editor

Search for "temp snapshot" in the .vbox file - that will take you to the `<snapshot>` node

Search for `<Image` - it is the partial name of a sub node under the `<snapshot>` node.

Replace all instances of the uuid of this  node (there should be 3) with the uuid of the .vdi filename in the \snapshots directory that you want to re-attach.

Test it out.

Comment: Add some of the XML lines that you've added or edited. And also provide what they look like before and after editing. It'll help readers.